# 特定のURLでアクセスがきたら特定のファイルを表示したい

Tags: nginx

#### 前提・実現したいこと

`http://localhost:8080/fuga`でアクセスが来た際にnginxのファイルシステムの`/var/www/html/hoge/fuga/index.html`を表示したいです。ご存知の方いましたら教えていただけるとありがたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

`http://localhost:8080/fuga`でアクセスが来た際のlocationの適切な書き方がわかりません。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
project
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── nginx
│   └── default.conf
└── app
    └── html
        ├── hoge
        │     └── fuga
        │          └── index.html
        └── index.html
```

project/docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: "3"

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

project/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./app /var/www/html
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

project/nginx/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/html/;
}
```

project/app/html/hoge/fuga/index.html

```html
hogefuga
```

project/app/index.html

```html
index
```

#### 検証方法

1. `$ cd /path/to/your/project`
2. `$ docker-compose up`
3. ブラウザで`http://localhost:8080/index.html`にアクセスするとindexと表示されます。

`http://localhost:8080/fuga`にアクセスした際に**hogefugaと表示させたい**です。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/357184) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: マルチポストという存在を知りませんでした。今後気をつけます。

Answer (score 1):

default.confに以下を追記しました。

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name  localhost;

  root /var/www/html/;

+  location /fuga {
+    root /var/www/html/hoge;
+  }
}
```